# Google Drive API file insert from buffer in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I am trying to figure out how to specify a `media_body` in the `files().insert()` method that comes from a buffer (or even a file-like object), rather than saving a temporary file and then using `MediaFileUpload` to insert into Google Drive and *then* deleting the temporary file.

Has anyone had any luck with this and could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code on appengine to upload from buffer:

```
    def insert_file(service, title, description, parent_id, mime_type, filebody):
        """Insert new file and deletes old file, if with same title.

        Args:
        service: Drive API service instance.
        title: Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
        description: Description of the file to insert.
        parent_id: Parent folder's ID.
        mime_type: MIME type of the file to insert.
        filebody: string, Bytes of body content.
        filename: Filename of the file to insert.
        Returns:
        Inserted file metadata if successful, None otherwise.
        """

        urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(45)

        # check if file is already there
        param = {}
        param['q'] = "title = '"+title+"'"
        filelist = service.files().list(**param).execute()
        if filelist:
            for f in filelist['items']:
                file_id = f['id']
                # logging.info("file: %s - %s" % (f['title'], file_id))
                # here we could delete the file, skip trash
                service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()

        media_body = MediaInMemoryUpload(filebody, mime_type)
        body = {
        'title': title,
        'description': description,
        'mimeType': mime_type
        }
        # Set the parent folder.
        if parent_id:
                body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]

        try:
                file = service.files().insert(
                    body=body,
                    media_body=media_body).execute()
                return file
        except errors.HttpError, error:
            logging.info('An error occured: %s' % error)
        return None
```